# JavaScript Выполнение функции внутри функции на второй клик

Tags: javascript, функции

После нажатия на кнопку, нужно что бы при следующем нажатии на карту на ней появлялся значок, однако он ставится после выполнения функции, не дожидаясь второго клика, вот код:

```
function buttonCreate(event){
var clickX = (event.layerX === undefined ? event.offsetX : event.layerX) + 1;

var clickY = (event.layerY === undefined ? event.offsetY : event.layerY) + 1;
document.getElementById('Navigation').onclick= ()=> buttonSet(clickX,clickY)
```

Где buttonSet добавляет кнопку

```
function buttonSet(x,y){
let b =document.createElement("area")
b.setAttribute("shape", "circle")
b.setAttribute("coords",  x+"," + y+"," +"12")
b.setAttribute("href", "assets/8168.png")
document.getElementById('Navigation')
  .appendChild(b)
```

Что не так ?

UPD 'Navigation' -id тэга  `<map>`

Comment: "UPD 'Navigation' -id тэга <map>" - ну и что?

Comment: Да,всё верно,спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function buttonCreate(event){
  document.getElementById('Navigation').onclick = () => console.log("second click");
  console.log("first click");
}
```

```html
<button id="Navigation" onclick="buttonCreate(event)">Test</button>
```